# How to set the ng-content of an Angular component in storybook?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I have a simple angular component that uses `<ng-content>`.  I am trying to put it in storybook, but I cannot figure out the syntax to specify the content with a variable.  Here is what I have now:

```
import {Header1Component} from './header1.component';
import {moduleMetadata, storiesOf} from '@storybook/angular';

const stories = storiesOf('Header 1', module)
    .addDecorator(
        moduleMetadata({
            declarations: [Header1Component],
        })
    );

stories.add('standard', () => {
    return {
        template:  `<app-header1>This is header 1</app-header1>`,
    };
});
```

This works correctly, but what I really want to do is bind that content to a variable, like this:

```
stories.add('standard', () => {
    const myValue = 'This is a header';
    return {
        template:  `<app-header1>{myValue}</app-header1>`,
    };
});
```

Sadly, this does not work.  When I try it, the content is empty.  What is the correct syntax?

Comment: I think what you want is "dynamic components" ... then set the value dynamically in the input. Your approach will definitaly not work in AOT.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable through props like this:

```
storiesOf('Button', module)
  .addDecorator(
    moduleMetadata({
        declarations: [ButtonComponent],
        imports: [BrowserModule, RouterTestingModule, CommonModule, MatButtonModule],
    }),
  )
  .add('SimpleButton', () => ({
    template: `<app-button [color]="color">{{content}}</app-button>`,
    props: {
        content: 'Click me',
        color: 'primary'
    },
  }))
```